# problem with Tikz and Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

when i put this code on beamer i got bad figure

```
\documentclass[leqno,mathserif]{beamer} \usepackage{graphics,bm}
\usetheme{Luebeck} \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \begin{document}
\begin{frame} \begin{figure}[h!] \centering \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm] {   \node (se) [draw,
shape=rectangle] {Existence Forte}; &   \node (yw) [draw,
shape=circle] {Yamada-watanab}; &   \node (ul) [draw,
shape=rectangle] {Unicité en Loi}; \\   \node (d1) [draw,
shape=circle] {Définition}; & &   \node (d2) [draw, shape=circle]
{Définition}; \\   \node (we) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Existence
Faible}; &   \node (ec) [draw, shape=circle] {Engelbert-Cherny}; &  
\node (pu) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Unicité Trajectorielle}; \\ };
\draw[->, thick] (se) -- (d1); \draw[->, thick] (d1) -- (we);
\draw[->, thick] (we) -- (yw); \draw[->, thick] (yw) -- (se);
\draw[->, thick] (se) -- (ec); \draw[->, thick] (ul) -- (ec);
\draw[->, thick] (ec) -- (pu); \draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (yw);
\draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (d2); \draw[->, thick] (d2) -- (ul);
\end{tikzpicture}  \caption{les différentes notions d'existence et
d'unicité}    \end{figure}   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
my purpose to have it like that:
[image]
Thanks to @samcarter but still looks like :
[image]

Comment: Looks like the scale is wrong.
You can use the `scale=<ratio>`, `x=<dimension>`, `y=<dimension>` and font commands to get it right...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[leqno,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usepackage{graphics,bm}
\usetheme{Luebeck} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
      \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm]{
                \node (se) [draw,shape=rectangle] {Existence Forte}; \&
                \node (yw) [draw,shape=circle] {Yamada-watanab}; \&
                \node (ul) [draw,shape=rectangle] {Unicité en Loi}; \\
                \node (d1) [draw,shape=circle] {Définition}; \& 
                \&   
                \node (d2) [draw, shape=circle] {Définition}; \\
                \node (we) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Existence Faible}; \&
                \node (ec) [draw, shape=circle] {Engelbert-Cherny}; \& 
                \node (pu) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Unicité Trajectorielle}; \\
            };
            \draw[->, thick] (se) -- (d1); \draw[->, thick] (d1) -- (we);
            \draw[->, thick] (we) -- (yw); \draw[->, thick] (yw) -- (se);
            \draw[->, thick] (se) -- (ec); \draw[->, thick] (ul) -- (ec);
            \draw[->, thick] (ec) -- (pu); \draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (yw);
            \draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (d2); \draw[->, thick] (d2) -- (ul);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ samcarter Thanks but can you please  make it small guz still lit of bit bad

Comment: @Educ I adjusted the size. Does this work for you? If yes, you could accept the answer